# Unable to use Acumatica's REST API in a website

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to use **Acumatica REST API (2020 R1)** in a website using the below code.

```
async function loginAcumatica(){
    try{
        const { apiUrl, clientId, clientSecret, username, password } = await getCredentials();
        const url = `${apiUrl}/identity/connect/token`;
        const result = await axios.post(url, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: `grant_type=password&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&username=${username}&password=${password}&scope=api`
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result;
        
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Client ID and Client Secret values are from Acumatica's Connected Application. I have used the **Resource Owner Password Credentials** Auth type while creating a new record in the Connected Application. **Username and Password** are user login credentials.

However, I am not able to connect to API and always keep getting errors. Is there something that I am missing or it's not feasible?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you shared the error message you are getting

Comment: I get HTTP Status code 415 with above request. But, even if I send the request in object format, I would get HTTP Status Code 400.

Comment: Did you look with the Chrome developer tools what is the full request and response? Is your page running in the same domain as your Acumatica website? If not I suspect this is failing due to CORS - Acumatica does not have CORS headers set by default and browsers will block cross-origin requests.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the request and verified with the records passed on API Endpoint and also checked the response.
Unfortunately, both are not in the same domain. And yes, we have requested Acumatica to enable CORS and they have confirmed it's been enabled. Also, we are now not getting the CORS error but only related to API request.

Answer (score 0):

Error 415 suggests an error with `body` content type.

Acumatica [Documentation](https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c) has the parameters passed in the URL instead of the body when using the `identity/connect/authorize` endpoint.

It is not specified which body content type to use with `identity/connect/token` endpoint. It could be different than: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I tried this way as well.

https://imgur.com/Rowj2Ko

And I get this result.
"message":"["Request failed with status code 400"]"

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I am trying to connect to Acumatica API through Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow where based on the documentation (2020 R1 Integration Development Guide), it says it needs grant_type, client_id, client_secret, username, password and scope in request body.

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica REST API is designed in a way that it can't be consumed with Javascript with API Libraries such as fetch as it's deemed as unsafe since the login credentials and secrets would be exposed.